# Block with 2 area ( custom shape )

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I need to do something like that ( image ) in CSS/HTML and i am not sure how to achieve this :

[image]

Specification :

- The block is split in 2 areas ( 50/50 )
- Each area must contain a background-image and text
- Each area must be clickable

Anyone have idea how i can achieve this ?

Comment: You're supposed to show us what you coded and we're supposed to tell you why it's not working. Right now it's not working because you didn't code anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something line this.

Note: left .inner block should have large padding-left. Right .inner block should have large padding-right;

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scene {
  margin: 0 -60px; /* use this to adjust images */
  height: 100%;
}

.part {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 -60px; /* use this to adjust images */
  padding: 85px 200px; /* use this to adjust text */
  display: block;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.part--first .inner {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/);
}

.part--second .inner {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scene">
     <a href="#" class="part part--first">
       <span class="inner">lorem</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="part part--second">
      <span class="inner">ipsum</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```